# Content is not rendered in output though mentioned in code.

Tags: css, wordpress

I can't figure out why I can not view the images/text/buttons on my webpage - but I can see it is there in the code?  I can not find any CSS hiding it.  Please help!
http://soundcues.net/wordpress/instruments/

Here is a sample of code not displaying:

```
<div id="masonry-container">                  
<article data-filters="" class="item   ">

        <a class="image-link no-frame" href="http://soundcues.net/wordpress/instruments/guitarmonics-acoustic">
        <!--        <span class="image-overlay"></span>-->
        <!--        <span class="overlay-thumbnail"><i class="--><!--"></i></span>-->
        <img width="191" height="173" class="prime-image post-image" alt="Acoustics GuitarMonics" src="/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/GuitarMonics_Acoustic_Square_Website.png">    </a>

    <div class="description image">
        <div style="text-align:center;">
<h3 style="font-size:16px; font-weight:bold;">Acoustic GuitarMonics</h3>

<a style="background-color:#444444;" href="http://soundcues.net/wordpress/instruments/guitarmonics-acoustic" class="btn medium ">DETAILS</a>
</div>            </div>
</article>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have `opacity:0;` for `article.item` in your css code. This of course makes everything fully transparent.

Comment: +1 Further to this -  I expect that there's a fadeIn of some kind which should be run. However, there are several errors in the console which probably prevent the fadeIn from happening.

Comment: @LeeTaylor is right, your JS code is broken. You'd still be better of doing that fadein effect in CSS instead.

Comment: Thanks so much, that was an easy fix! I purchased the WP Theme so not sure where to update that JS code or why this stopped properly showing.